# List processes with their launching command line

Tags: windows-server-2003, command-line-interface, process

I'm looking for a Windows feature or third-party tool that can produce a list of active processes (as in the task manager) with the command line used to start each process.

e.g. if I launch "php.exe -q script.php" in a command line, during the execution of my process, I'd like to see this command in the list and not only "php.exe"

Tasklist, process explorer, taskinfo... can't give this information and/or make it available in a text format. Do you know if such tools/features exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
wmic process list full /format:htable > wmic_task_list.html
```

or

```
wmic process get Name,ProcessId,CommandLine /format:table > wmic_task_list.txt
```

See `wmic process list /format /?` or `wmic process get /format /?` for a list of valid output formats.

Comment: On my system `table` worked with normal user rights, while `htable` as well as the other XSL-based formats required admin privileges.

Comment: wmic.exe is no longer provided in windows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic